# Importing the username of owner when importing file in SAS

Tags: file, import, attributes, sas

I'm currently importing a few hundred files into SAS using a looped infile statement based on a table containing all the paths and filenames of interest. What I'm now looking to do is import the attributes of each file to get the username of who created each file. I've been trying to use finfo to get the 'Owner' variable but not sure if this is the right one to use. The code I've been using looks a little like this:

```
filename fileref 'file.csv';                                                                                                          
data a(drop=fid);                                                                                                                       
infile fileref truncover obs=1;                                                                                                       
fid=fopen('fileref');     
fnum = foptnum(fid); 
Bytes=finfo(fid,'File Size bytes)');                                                                                                 
crdate=finfo(fid,'Create Time');                                                                                                      
moddate=finfo(fid,'Last Modified');  

owner=foptname(fid,2);
owner2 = finfo(fid,owner); 
Owner1 = finfo(fid,'Owner');
run;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using? The behaviour of `finfo` is OS-dependent.

Comment: Sorry - I'm using windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example using the `dir /q` approach before mentioned. It should be useful to read in multiple files within a folder while retaining the file attributes.

```
%let target_dir = %str(C:\csv_files);
filename DrLst pipe "dir ""&target_dir.\*.csv"" /Q";
%let DELIM   = ' ' ;
data readFiles;
    length infile_path
           filename $255 
           line $1024 
           owner $17 
           temp $16 ;
    infile DrLSt length=reclen;
    input line $varying1024. reclen;
    /*For each csv file found, obtain the file information and read the file contents*/
    if    index(line,"<DIR>") eq 0 and substr(line,1,1) in('0','1') then do;
        createDate = input( scan( line, 1, &DELIM ), mmddyy8. ) ;
        createTime = input( scan( line, 2, &DELIM ), time10. ) ;
        size       = input( scan( line, 4, &DELIM ), best8.) ;
        owner      =        scan( line, 5, &DELIM ) ;

        /*Parsing the filename is tricky*/
        filename = scan( line, 6, &DELIM ) ;
        ndx = index( line, scan( filename, 1 )) ;
        filename = substr( line, ndx ) ;

        /*Now read in the found csv file*/
        infile_path = cat("&target_dir.\",strip(filename));
        infile temp filevar=infile_path dsd dlm=',' end=temp_end;
        do until (temp_end);
            input csvVar1 : $char50.
                  vscVar2 : $char50.;
            output;
        end;
    end;
    drop ndx line temp;
run;
```

Comment: Sweet! God speed.

Answer (score 0):

The file owner's username might not be accessible via the `finfo` function for files in your environment. You can list the names of the available items for a file by running the following:

```
data _null_;
fileref = "myfile";
rc = filename(fileref,"C:\temp\class.csv");
put rc=;
fid = fopen(fileref);
put fid=;
nopts = foptnum(fid);
do i = 1 to nopts;
  optname = foptname(fid,i);
  put optname=;
end;
rc = fclose(fid);
run;
```

If `file owner` or something like that isn't listed for files in your environment then this approach isn't going to work. You'll need to get the name some other way, e.g. by piping a `dir /Q` command for the file in question.

An example of this using file control functions would be:

```
data _null_;
fileref = "myfile";
/*
The line output by the command below will look something like this:
28/09/2016  13:29               437 user                   class.csv
*/
rc = filename(fileref,"dir /q c:\temp\class.csv | findstr class.csv",'pipe');
fid = fopen(fileref,'s');
rc = fread(fid);
length junk $100 username $32;
/*fget reads 1 word at a time, so throw away the 3 before the username*/
do i = 1 to 3; 
rc = fget(fid, junk);
end;
rc = fget(fid, username);
rc = fclose(fid);
put _all_;
run;
```

If you are really keen, it is also possible to replicate all of the above in pure macro code, by wrapping every function call in `%sysfunc()`.

Comment: How about the example of the `dir /q` piping method as well? ;-)

Comment: @RobertPenridge I'll provide an example if the asker is interested. For all I know it's possible they're using `finfo` because they have to live with `option noxcmd`, in which case there may be no solution.

Comment: @user667489 Thanks for that bit of code, I tried using it but I think you're right the owner information isn't available using `finfo`. Could you provide an example of the `dir /q` method though please? I can still use cmd commands.